# Stored Procedures in PHP PDO with named parameters

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I am trying to solve this issue where my database admin provided me with this Stored Procedure to call with named parameters and since I use PHP 7 with PDO and SQL Server, it is difficult to get correct syntax and execute successfully.

This is what my Dbase Admin provided me with:

```
exec subscription @customer_key='2AB407313144', @invoice_key='0022BE6C4912'
```

This is what I tried from some similar questions, result: fail

```
$sql = 'EXEC subscription :customer_key, :invoice_key';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':customer_key', $_SESSION['customer_key']); 
$stmt->bindParam(':invoice_key', $_SESSION['inv_key']); 

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: exec subscription @customer_key=:customer_key, @invoice_key=:invoice_key

Comment: @YourCommonSense tried that, no positive result.

Comment: Did you try setting the Statement type as a Stored Procedure (as opposed to general query)?

Comment: @J.Murray sorry Im new to the scene, can you please provide an example, didnt quite understand what your saying?

Comment: @RohanTapiyawala  `$stmt->bindParam(':customer_key', $_SESSION['customer_key']); $stmt->bindParam(':invoice_key', $_SESSION['invoice_key']);` may help.

Comment: @Zhorov tried that didnt work either

Comment: @RohanTapiyawala Your statement (after the last edit) seems correct, have you execute `session_start()` before any output and did you check the output from `var_dump($_SESSION)?`.

Comment: What does your stored proc do? Run actions, run `SELECT`, multiple returns? Try unnamed parameters but positional parameters: `EXEC subscription ?, ?`  ... `$stmt->bindParam(1, ...); $stmt->bindParam(2, ...)`